# change custom data- value after ajax post success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okie so I thought [this was a neat looking bit of css](http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-love-buttons) and thought I would try to plug it into my website and replace my existing "recommend/recommended" bit of ajax/query that is working just fine, but is not as well, pretty.

I have gotten the text to update from "`Love It`" too "`Loved It!`" but I cannot get the numeric value (total loves/recommends) to update.

It is using that value of `data-counter` and I cannot seem to figure out the method to get that value to update after a successful ajax POST.

```
<a href="#" id="love" class="lovebtn" data-count="<?=$TotalRecommendations;?>">&#9829; Love it</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#love').click(function(){
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "loved.php",
            data: "id=123",
            success: function(msg) {
                document.getElementById('love').innerHTML = "&#9829; Loved!";
                document.getElementsByAttribute('data-count').innerHTML = "<?=($TotalRecommendations+1);?>";
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried to use a few methods, include using the `document.getElementsByAttribute('data-count').innerHTML = "<?=($TotalRecommendations+1);?>";` but I am getting stumped here. I also tried using `document.getElementById('data-count').innerHTML` but that did not work either.

Could somebody share with me what the technique is to get this `data-count` to be updated after a successful ajax post?

Comment: You should first show to the user that his vote has been saved, and then do the ajax query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you are updating your attribute value as

```
document.getElementById("love").setAttribute("data-count","<?=$TotalRecommendations+1;?>");
```

Comment: Woot!!!  So its a setAttribute() with two parameters, first defining the custom made data-whatever! Got it, and makes total sense. Thanks Tushar!

Comment: @Abela Happy to help... and Plz accept the answer if you solved your query..thnaks :)